# Getting Linking error LNK2019`when using multiple files

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the following files in visual studio 2010:

The tutorial is taken from [here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/)

**/* callback.c */**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"reg_callback.h"

/* callback function definition goes here */
void my_callback(void)
{
    printf("inside my_callback\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    /* initialize function pointer to
    my_callback */
    callback ptr_my_callback=my_callback;                           
    printf("This is a program demonstrating function callback\n");
    /* register our callback function */
    register_callback(ptr_my_callback);                             
    printf("back inside main program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**/* reg_callback.h */**

```
typedef void (*callback)(void);
void register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback);
```

**/* reg_callback.c */**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"reg_callback.h"

/* registration goes here */
void register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback)
{
    printf("inside register_callback\n");
    /* calling our callback function my_callback */
    (*ptr_reg_callback)();                                  
}
```

But I am getting this linking error :

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   register_callback(void (__cdecl*)(void))"
>   (?register_callback@@YAXP6AXXZ@Z) referenced in function
>   _main D:\VS\test\ww\ww\ww.obj ww

What is wrong here I am unable to understand.Please help.

Comment: You to wrap the header in `extern "C" { ... }` IIRC

Comment: @leppie can you write exactly how do wrap ? I did extern "C"
 
 {
  typedef void (*callback)(void);
void register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback);
}  but did not work

Comment: you code compiles ok with `gcc callback.c reg_callback.c`, you should give more infomation about your VS project (W32 console or W32 window, etc...)